# Possible to hide or de-prioritize an application from spotlight?

Tags: spotlight, quicktime

Is it possible to hide an application from Spotlight?

I have an annoyance of sorts. This will probably seem trivial to others, but it happens to me enough that I find it rather frustrating. I have Quicken and of course, Quicktime is bundled with macOS. If I bring up spotlight and start typing `quic` it is showing quicken. But if I proceed to put in the "k" before hitting enter, spotlight switches from Quicken to Quicktime and that's what ends up getting opened. Often there is just enough of a delay that I see Quicken while pressing enter.

Since I do not use Quicktime at all (vlc person), I would just force uninstall it, but it seems like there should be a way to hide applications from spotlight or give some applications priority over others.

Comment: It's probably learning from your mistake, unfortunately. You keep confirming its guess.

Comment: You can add new "tag" to the Quicken.app and then search by the tag. To add a tag, open Get Information (⌘+i) on *.app file and add tag. For example you can add something like `qn` as a tag.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Spotlight learns from your actions. The more you choose QuickTime for a certain input, the more that result will appear as the Top Hit for that search phrase. Try typing your phrase which shows QuickTime first, then choose Quicken. Keep doing this and it will learn that you want Quicken instead. This might take a few tries depending on how many times you incorrectly taught it first.

Alternatively, you can prevent something from appearing in Spotlight by adding it to the Privacy list. Open System Preferences → Spotlight, choose the Privacy tab, then drag QuickTime Player.app from Applications into this list.

Comment: The privacy tip did the trick!